# Salesforce - Create an item of an Object that does not have a tab

Tags: salesforce

Is there a way to create a new item of a custom Object that does not have a tab?  The environment I am using is maxed out in tabs so I cannot create a new one which would easily allow me to create a new item.

I'd rather not have to write up a Visualforce page to do this, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom link on the left side if you know the prefix of your Custom Object.

i.e. : "/a0E"